# Call python function with default arguments before other arguments?

Tags: python, numpy, arguments

Can I call a function using the default value for some arguments but not for all?

Take  `numpy.random.lognormal(mean=0.0, sigma=1.0, size=None)` as an example,
I want to call it with default mean and sigma but not default size.

Something in my mind is like `np.random.lognormal(_,_,2)`, but this does not work

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Simply provide the argument you want to override:

```
np.random.lognormal(size=2)
```

This is precisely where *named* arguments become useful.